# Deleted Gstreamer codec and can't play mp3 or mp4 files

Tags: mime-type

I had accidentally deleted one of the G-streamer codec and now i can't play any mp3 or mp4 file. Whenever, I try to open one of these files it gives a message of "Additional MIME type require". Please help.

Comment: Please be more detailed, you openend the file with what application and what is the output exactly saying?

Comment: I opened "ubuntu software" application and then i selected G-streamer multimedia codec and deleted one and from then onwards whenever i open any mp3 or mp4 files it always gives the message "additional mime type requires".